# Not able to access Internal load balancer from outside of VPC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, vpc

I have created one internal load balancer and application deployed on that internal network. For testing purpose I have created one instance in same VPC called "instance1". I am able to curl to load balancer from this instance1 but I am not able to ping this internal load balancer from outside of VPC. 
My future plan is to deploy UI on external load balancer and call internal load balancer from there.

Query is, as I am not able to connect to internal load balancer from outside how my UI instance will be able to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

**Internal** Loadbalancers are for **internal** connections only. For reaching out your load balancer from a different network, you can use [VPC Peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering) (connect two GCP network) or use [Interconnect products](https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/) (VPN or Direct connection) for secured/dedicated intranet access.

If your application is intended to be accessible from the outside world (the internet), you can use an **external** [load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https) (Layer 4 or Layer 7 if your application is HTTP based).